# Gitbook API returning HTTP code 429

Tags: https, gitbook, http-status-code-429

I wrote a Gitbook API Android application in Java. However, I'm having a problem
when I use the API to access pubic book data with an HTTPS request from my Android device: the API returns HTTPS response code 429. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You've tried too often, too fast. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429 Check the documentation of the API about rate limits.

Comment: thank you, I'm readed this  documentation,my app every request that API service take a few minutes interval.but It's occur same problem